# How to correctly add and remove specific items from an array within state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement some functionality that will allow for the name of a checkbox to be pushed to an array in the components state and also to have that name removed when the checkbox is unchecked, I can push to the array just fine, it's removing items from it that I'm having trouble with.

I've tried using splice but the issue I'm having is it seems that the array is lagging one action behind, thus not allowing me to splice out the correct item.

```
handleCheckboxChange = event => {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    this.setState({
      check: [...this.state.check, event.target.name]
    });
} else if (!event.target.checked) {
    let index = this.state.check.indexOf(event.target.name);
    this.setState({
      check: this.state.check.splice(index, 1)
    });
  }
};
```

Expected result is that items will be added and removed from the array as the user checks or unchecks the corresponding checkbox.

Comment: Bear in mind, setState() is asynchronous. It may well happen as you expect, just not on the timeframe you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation of splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), it returns the removed items.

> An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

So when you do this:

```
   this.setState({
      check: this.state.check.splice(index, 1)
    });
```

you are basically modifying directly `this.state.check` by using splice on it, and then setting it with `this.setState({ check: [removed items] })`.

you should don't modify state variables directly, and do something like this:

```
this.setState({
     check: this.state.check.filter((item, i) => {
          return index !== i;
     })
})
```

`filter` creates a new array, and do not modify the current array. You can also use `slice` which uses a shallow copy of the array, but I think this is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is `.filter`. [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Also you should note that `.splice` is mutating the array, which means you're mutating the state object with .splice and then changing state with setState(), which means your altering it twice. I believe you want to avoid mutations and only change it with setState().

Try this solution, (some opinions about formatting were added in):

```
handleCheckboxChange = event => {
  const {checked, name} = event.target
  if (checked) {
    this.setState({
      check: [...this.state.check, name]
    });
} else {
    this.setState({
      check: this.state.check.filter(item => item !== name)
    });
  }
};
```

Edit: spaniard posted the same solution at the same time as me, but I'll leave this here as the implementations differ slightly.